# What happened to the "Request Update" button on contact?

Tags: standard-field

In the past, there was a 'Request Update' button on a contact page.
This sent the contact a type of SF form, where the user could update/confirm his details.

[image]
Anyone knows what happened to this button? I can't find it anywhere.

Also, there are 2 fields that are related to this button, but they still exist on the contact

- Last Stay-in-Touch Request Date  LastCURequestDate
- Last Stay-in-Touch Save Date LastCUUpdateDate

Comment: Seems to be retired at Summer'17 release - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Stay-in-Touch-Request-Retirement-with-Summer-17&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: @kurunve Seems plausible. I would have added that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Salesforce [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Stay-in-Touch-Request-Retirement-with-Summer-17&type=1&mode=1) - given feature has been retired during Summer 17 release.

As described in linked article, Salesforce has not created a replacement for Stay-in-Touch Request, and advices to use other marketing automations tools.